# How can I fill an empty JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript

I've looked all over online for something that could aid me to fill an empty array with given values the user inputs from a text box that will get stored inside an array.

So far I have the following code:

```
var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
var message = document.getElementById("text-here");
message.innerHTML += text + " " + "<br />" + "<br />";
  var x = [];
  x.push(text);


  console.log(x);
```

When I input something in the textbox and see what happens in the console it tends to replace the previous value that was sent there first.

For example, if I wrote "Hello", this will get sent into the array so it'll be seen as:

```
["Hello"]
```

But if I type in something again, hoping that the result will continue to store the data being inputted inside, it does this:

*Writes down "Hi" in the text box:

```
["Hi"]
```

I want the result to be something like this:

```
["Hello", "Hi"]
```

I am aware my code does need tweaking and I am doing something wrong which is causing that result, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm looking for an answer in **vanilla** JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: You are re-initialising the array every time before you add an element. Just make sure it's initialised once and then you only push to it. You likely need to take that initialisation out of the event listener.

Comment: Declare  var x = []; before function and remove declaration from your function.

Comment: What about making your array vairable "x" global, not local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are redeclaring variable x and initializing it with an empty array, every time when you run that code. Make the x a global variable by moving it out of the current function or block

```
var x = [];
```

Another Block

```
var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
var message = document.getElementById("text-here");
message.innerHTML += text + " " + "<br />" + "<br />";
x.push(text);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var x = [];
    
    function() {    
    var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("text-here");
    message.innerHTML += text + " " + "<br />" + "<br />";
      
      x.push(text);


  console.log(x);
}
```

something like this should fix your problem. You were declaring x as an empty array every time you ran your javascript which would reset it to an empty arry.